# Polymer dom-repeat and displaying result of iron-ajax call

Tags: javascript, json, polymer

I have a feed of GP Practice addresses the start of which is as follows (not the whole feed which is over 16000 entries - still got to figure out paging)

```
    [{"Address1":"73 UPPER WICKHAM LANE","Address2":"WELLING","Address3":"KENT","Address4":"","Address5":"","CloseDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000+0000)\/","ContactName":"","ContactTelephone":"020 88541910","EmailAddress":"","LastUpdatedDate":"\/Date(1434749040000+0100)\/","Name":"(GPSI) DR AC BARUAH","OpenDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000+0000)\/","OrgSubTypeCode":"B","PCTCode":"TAK","Postcode":"DA16 3AF","PracticeCode":"Y00789","PracticeType":"0","SendToEDTHub":false,"SendToEmail":false,"SendToPrinter":true,"Status":"C"},
{"Address1":"73 UPPER WICKHAM LANE","Address2":"","Address3":"WELLING","Address4":"KENT","Address5":"","CloseDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000+0000)\/","ContactName":"","ContactTelephone":"020 88541910","EmailAddress":"","LastUpdatedDate":"\/Date(1434749040000+0100)\/","Name":"(GPSI) DR AP DHITAL","OpenDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000+0000)\/","OrgSubTypeCode":"B","PCTCode":"TAK","Postcode":"DA16 3AF","PracticeCode":"Y00788","PracticeType":"0","SendToEDTHub":false,"SendToEmail":false,"SendToPrinter":true,"Status":"C"},
{"Address1":"2 CHURCH AVENUE","Address2":"","Address3":"SIDCUP","Address4":"KENT","Address5":"","CloseDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000+0000)\/","ContactName":"","ContactTelephone":"020 83021114","EmailAddress":"","LastUpdatedDate":"\/Date(1434749040000+0100)\/","Name":"(GPSI) DR HL BHATTAD","OpenDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000+0000)\/","OrgSubTypeCode":"B","PCTCode":"TAK","Postcode":"DA14 6BU","PracticeCode":"Y00791","PracticeType":"0","SendToEDTHub":false,"SendToEmail":false,"SendToPrinter":true,"Status":"C"}
    .
    .
    .
```

this is returned with the mime-type application/json to the calling application

The following code is the HTML snippet which I thought would make a call to get the data and display it.

```
            <paper-material elevation="1">
                <div id="GPPracticeContainer">
                    GP List
                    {{data}}
                    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}"
                        <p>{{item.Name}}</p>
                    </template>

                </div>
            </paper-material>
        </paper-header-panel>
        <iron-ajax auto id="GPCollection" 
                   url="/GPPractices.ashx" 
                   handle-as="json" 
                   last-response="{{data}}"
                   on-response="handleGPCollection">

        </iron-ajax>
```

and finally the javascript

```
<script>

    function handleKeyPress(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert('off to search for something!');
        }
    };

    Polymer({
        is: "practice-list",
        hideSearch: {
            type: Boolean,
            value: false
        },
        handleGPCollection: function(request) {
            alert('GP Practices collected ' + request);
        },
        ready: function () {
            this.hideSearch = true;
            this.$.searchText.keyup(function (e) {
                alert('off to search for something!');
            });
        },
        srchandler: function () {
            // search for contents of search box is showing, otherwise show it.
            if (!this.hideSearch)
            {
                alert('off to search for something!');
            }
            else {
                this.hideSearch = !this.hideSearch;
                if (!this.hideSearch) {
                    this.$.searchText.focus();
                }
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

Trouble is although the alert box appears showing the data has been read - and returns Object CustomEvent No data appears.

anyone know how I can

a) Find out what is going wrong
b) Get it to display say the Name of each practice

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am missing the closing'>' of the template. It should read

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
    <p><span>{{item.PracticeCode}}</span> - <span>{{item.Name}}</span></p>
</template>
```